# Cassandra Appender - How to Log ONLY error messages?

Tags: cassandra, log4j2

I am using Cassandra appender, console and file appenders in my application. I want to store only `ERROR` messages in Cassandra table Logs whereas store `INFO` messages to Console and file.

Below is the `log4j2.xml` file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"</Property>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">./log</Property>
        <Property name="MINLEVEL">INFO</Property>
        <Property name="FILEMAXSIZE">800MB</Property>
        <Property name="MAXFILES">5</Property>x
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout  pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="ROLLING" fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/abc.log"
                     filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/abc-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${FILEMAXSIZE}" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${MAXFILES}"/>
        </RollingFile>
         <Cassandra name="Cassandra" clusterName="TestCluster" keyspace="Employee" table="Logs" bufferSize="10"  username="tomcat" password="password">
            <SocketAddress host="IPaddress" port="9042"/>
            <ColumnMapping name="userid" pattern="%uuid{TIME}" type="java.util.UUID"/>
            <ColumnMapping name="logger" pattern="%logger"/>
            <ColumnMapping name="message" pattern="%message"/>
            <ColumnMapping name="level" pattern="%level"/>
             <ColumnMapping name="timestamp" literal="now()"/>
        </Cassandra>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${MINLEVEL}" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ROLLING"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="abc.xyz" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Cassandra" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```

In the last segment when I change the level to `${MINLEVEL}` i.e **INFO**, then it works but ERROR is not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that additivity is set to false, this is preventing to duplicate the messages to the `root` and `abc.xyz` loggers. If you set additivity to false, it will be sent to both loggers.

More information is available in this [blog entry](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/).

Comment: Thanks! additivity is set to false. Even if I remove the additivity attribute, it does not write to Cassandra Logs table when level is changed to ERROR. The issue seems to be with Cassandra appender.                                                        <Root level="${MINLEVEL}" additivity="false">
   <AppenderRef ref="console" />
   <AppenderRef ref="ROLLING"/>
  </Root>
  <Logger name="aero.sita" level="ERROR">
  <AppenderRef ref="Cassandra" />
   <AppenderRef ref="console" />
   
  </Logger>
  
  
 </Loggers>